# Sublime text automatically scrolling on find

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I want to find a string in Sublime text which is a time stamp. For eg. 03:46:23. When I enter 03:46 it starts scrolling to the found text . I enter the full timestamp and I get to the point where the string is in the file on line 100. From there I want to search forward for another string 'test' which is on line 150 . However as soon as I clear the text in the Find box Sublime Text scrolls back to the position where I started searching for '03:46:23' on line 2000. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you describe you need to re-start the find tool after the 1st match has been found but before you type the 2nd search query. i.e. Before you clear the text in the find panel press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> keys - doing this will cause the 2nd search to begin from the position in the file of the 1st match.

Step by step instructions using your example:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to start the find tool (<kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> on OSX)
- Type `03:46:23` to do the 1st search - `03:46:23` should now be highlighted in the file
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to re-start the find tool - even though the find panel is already open & focused
- Type `test` to do the 2nd search - the 2nd search will start from the position in the file where the 1st search matched